# Setting DateTimePicker value from another DateTimePicker loses UTC?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a DateTimePicker which is formatted as UTC: true:

```
<DateTimePicker id="massStartDate" displayFormat="dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm" secondsStep="60" width="20%" minDate="{config>/minDate}" 
    value="{path : 'config>/jobShift/massStart', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: { strictParsing: true , UTC: true, pattern: 'dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss' }}"
    placeholder="Enter Start Date..."/>
```

The value of this DateTimePicker is to be propagated down to several other DateTimePickers in a loop.

However, when I pass the value across it loses an hour.  The other DateTimePickers are also UTC: true:

```
<DateTimePicker minDate="{config>/minDate}" displayFormat="dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm" secondsStep="60" 
    value="{path : 'ConstraintStartTimestamp', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: { strictParsing: true , UTC: true, pattern: 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm' }}"
    placeholder="Enter Start Date..."/>
```

How do I stop the other DateTimePickers losing an hour?

**Value from the initial DateTimePicker:**

Wed Jul 12 2023 10:27:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

**Value on the other DateTimePicker (which is the same value as above):**

Wed Jul 12 2023 10:27:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

Actual Dates shown on the UI:

[image: Issue]

Code to fill the dates:

```
for(var i = 0; i < oItems.length; i++) {
    var oContext = oItems[i].getBindingContext();
    dStartDate = new Date(dpStartDate.getValue());
    dEndDate = new Date(dpEndDate.getValue());
    this.getModel().setProperty(oContext.getPath() + "/ConstraintStartTimestamp", dStartDate);
    this.getModel().setProperty(oContext.getPath() + "/ConstraintFinishTimestamp", dEndDate);
}
```

Thanks,

Fish

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Rather than using DatePicker.getValue(), I used the binding:

value="path : '{config>/jobShift/massStart'...

Comment: Yes, working with binding is much preferred. Additionally, whenever you plan to instantiate JS Date, please use `UI5Date.getInstance` instead: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c9e61dc157a40c19460660ece8368bc.html#loio6c9e61dc157a40c19460660ece8368bc/section_ui5date See also other content in the link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).